# Is the procedure for an oil change different for a turbocharged engine?

Tags: oil-change, turbocharger

I recently upgraded my ride to a 2011 Taurus SHO. I usually try to change the oil as soon as possible after a vehicle purchase, just to be safe. I'm not used to turbo cars, as this is my first, so I was curious if there are additional steps or considerations when changing the oil.

I know that oil is used to cool and lubricate the turbo, and I'm fairly certain that this must be supplied from the oil pan, but I'm not positive. If it is its own closed system, I imagine it needs to be drained and filled separately (and with it's own filter).

I don't think that is the case, but is there anything different to changing the oil compared to a NA engine?

I'm guessing that the oil drains out of the turbo when you shut off the car, just like it does from all the crevices in the engine, so that there is nothing more for me to do except drain it from the oil pan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The process is just the same. The turbo on every engine that I've worked on gets its oil supply from the same system as the rest of the engine.

Answer (score 2):

While I can't cite any sources for this (google is just turning up pages and pages of forum posts about it) I have heard from several people that you should pre-fill your oil filter with oil before putting it on with a turbo, as you don't want the turbo running dry for any amount of time due to the High RPMs.

I can't speak to if this is necessary (check your manual!) It sounds like a good idea, and as long as you don't let the tamper seal from the bottle get into the filter, you should be fine.

I'll try and find sources tonight.

Answer (score -1):

The procedure for changing the oil in a car that has a turbo is the same as cars that don't have turbos. However you do have to change the oil more frequently.